# How to say "because the time is limited, we stop at this point"

Tags: sentence, phrase-requests

I am in the process of writing my PhD thesis. In the introduction, after introducing the research problems and explaining the partial result achieved I want to say that because the time is limited we have to stop at this point and I want to continue the research in the future to get a complete answer of the problem. I don't know how to say this in a proper English, can you help me please.

Comment: For the first part of the sentence: "due to time constraints". For the second: "we had to suspend the research program at that degree of progress".

Comment: Great. What about the last part "continue the research in the future to get better results"

Comment: Your wording is ok. Alternative:  "research should further continue to improve outcome".

Comment: Time for what? Researching? Thinking? Writing? Presenting?

Answer (score 1):

"because time is limited we shall stop at this point" is perfectly fine. 
Other than that you've got things like "for the sake of time...".

In the context you're speaking of you might want to use something that has less possibility of being interpreted as "I was rushing". 
Consider ways that you might say "I achieved the practical step I set out to accomplish."

Some possibilities:
"These results conclude stage one of the study."
"Given sufficient time this line of research will provide further detail."
"These results are within the practical scope of this project."